# Flutter Floating Action Button issue in opening SimpleDialog or Bottom Sheet

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button

I have a Main Dart File with the Bottom Navigation bar and Floating action button.
I am trying to open SimpleDialog or showModalBottomSheet when the user taps on the Button. But this is not working.

I have tried another way to open it. But that also does not work.
I am sure the problem is with the context. With the right context, the dialog should get open.
What's the right solution to tackle this As if this floating action button is added in one of the Screens from the Bottom navigation then the BottomSheetModal gets opened.

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return  SimpleDialog(
            title:Text("hello"),
          );
        },
        fullscreenDialog: true
    ));
  }
```

Sample code can be found here

https://github.com/parmarravi/Flutter-BottomSheet-Bug

Comment: why are you using Navigator? `onPressed` you can use `return showDialog`. It should work

Comment: This is another way I have tried out so that with the right context bottom sheet should get open. But I was wrong. The bottom Sheet modal does not open when clicked on the floating action button. But when this action button is added in one of the menu items eg: -Home from the bottom navigation then it gets opened.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFDD),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
            const Radius.circular(20),
          ),
          side: BorderSide(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            width: 2,
          ),
        ),
        title: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'title',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        content: Container(
          child: Text(
            'body!',
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: (){},
              child: Text(
                'Ok',
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have uploaded sample code  https://github.com/parmarravi/Flutter-BottomSheet-Bug